# bash: wget: command not found

Tags: wget, chrome-book, chrome-os

I'm using `ASUS-Chromebook-Flip-C302CA` / `Google Chrome OS` - `Version 65.0.3325.35 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)` and I'm trying to follow [Visual Studio Code for Chromebooks and Raspberry Pi](https://code.headmelted.com/), yet failing to execute last step with following error:

```
chronos@localhost ~ $ . <( wget -O - https://code.headmelted.com/installers/chromebook.sh )
bash: wget: command not found
chronos@localhost ~ $
```

`wget`:

```
chronos@localhost ~ $ whereis wget
wget:
chronos@localhost ~ $ which wget
which: no wget in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin)
chronos@localhost ~ $ find / -name wget >/dev/null 2>&1
chronos@localhost ~ $
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alternative:

- `curl` - transfer a URL

> `. <( curl --silent https://code.headmelted.com/installers/chromebook.sh )`

Comment: I have no idea, what is running on the chromebooks, but most probably there is some type of a package manager. You should simply install the package containing wget. If it is a debian-based distribution, then the command is `apt-get install wget`.

Comment: @peterh There is no package manager on Chromebooks or ChromeOS based devices. It's not a traditional Linux distribution like Debian or OpenWrt. You install the latest update for the image that you are running and may be Android apps but that's it. Tinkering and poking around the filesystem is allowed but they got rid of everything else that could introduce more complexity and possible breakage.

Comment: @LiveWireBT ... Behold Chrome Brew, the package manager for ChromeOS: -https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew

Comment: @jeffmcneill Thanks I think I read about this somewhere before but didn't invest any time looking for the project site. It may be useful in some cases but ChromeOS devices are still intended as appliances from my point of view (though I do run a full Linux on mine).

Comment: @LiveWireBT it appears that there is a bit of segmenting in ChromeOS these days, with a variety of more capable devices (both ARM and Intel processors). They still like to limit the ram in most of these. In any case, shell apps generally don't take a lot of resources. I find I can install nearly all command line apps that I generally run on servers and ran on a now-dead Macbook Air. There's been a lot of progress on these devices over the years, both hardware and software. ChromeOS came out of Gentoo, hence the "not a traditional distribution" under the hood, but that also means more flexible.

Comment: removing --silent made it work for me

Answer (score 3):

`wget` has been removed from recent versions of `ChromeOS` which includes what's installed on the `ASUS-Chromebook-Flip-C302CA'.

You can use the `curl` command to download the files instead.

Comment: Any example of downloading files using curl?

Comment: Check the `man` page for `curl`. You can start with `curl -o download.rpm http://www.website.com/file.rpm`